# LNK2005 making a C wrapper for C++ libphonenumber

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, libphonenumber, lnk2005

I have a cross platform C project and now I want to introduce the C++ based libphonenumber in my project changing as little as possible. The first attempt is to integrate it in Win32 using Visual Studio 2013 but it needs to work on iOS and Android as well later on.

so I created this header:

```
    #ifndef LIB_PN_WRAPPER_H
    #define LIB_PN_WRAPPER_H

      #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
      #endif

      char* tu_lpn_normalize(char* number);

      #ifdef __cplusplus
        }
      #endif
    #endif //LIB_PN_WRAPPER
```

and this cpp:

```
    #include "LibPNWrapper.h"
    #include "phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.h"

    using i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumberUtil;

    char* tu_lpn_normalize(char* number) {
      PhoneNumberUtil* util = PhoneNumberUtil::GetInstance();
      return "hello";
    }
```

But I get stuck with this linker error:

error LNK2005: "private: static unsigned int const i18n::phonenumbers::PhoneNumberUtil::kMinLengthForNsn" (?kMinLengthForNsn@PhoneNumberUtil@phonenumbers@i18n@@0IB) already defined in LibPNWrapper.obj

This is indeed declared and defined in phonenumberutil.h as:

static const size_t kMinLengthForNsn = 2;

and I understand that by including it in my cpp it is declared again. However I have tried to:

- Include it in the header file instead but then I had to change my files to compile as c++ instead and I still ended up with problems.
- To use a namespace in the cpp file but it did not help.

I am not sure if its because I mix C and C++ or if I am missing something else fundamental here.

All ideas welcome.

Comment: Is kMinLengthForNsn a global variable defined in your header? If so, you would have to use the keyword `extern` to use it properly.

Comment: Not really. kMinLengthForNsn is declared and defined in the header file of libphonenumber which is a library I do not want to make changes in. So adding extern is not an option.

Comment: I see. I read it wrong, it is well encapsulated inside the class from libphonenumber. Have you double checked your linking options for duplicate dynamic/static configuration?

Comment: I think they are not correct in having the definitions of static variables in the header file to start with. I moved them to the source file and it works now.
I posted a request to change this in github.
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/issues/686